# How to define a string method for a many to many relation in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

It is possible to define a `__str__` method on a model:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But how to define something like this for an automatically generated table through a ManyToManyField? Objects that represent a relationship between a person and a hobby are written like this:

`Person_hobbies object (1)`

Note that I am not talking about the `Hobby` object itself, but the object that represents the relation between a `Person` and a `Hobby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to define something like this for an automatically generated table through a `ManyToManyField`?

You can define the junction table model with the [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby, through='PersonHobby')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PersonHobby(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hobby = models.ForeignKey(Hobby, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'A string with the {self.person} and the {self.hobby}'
```

Migrating to a junction model for a `ManyToManyField` is however not that easy. If it is possible, I would delete migrations that include the `ManyToManyField` and recreate a migration.

Comment: I recreated the migrations and it worked. Thanks!